# BigQuery Scheduled Query Limit Bytes

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using Scheduled Queries on BigQuery to do some daily tasks.

I am wondering if there is any way to limit the maximum amount of scanned bytes of a Scheduled Query.

There is a setting, [Custom cost controls](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas), to set a limit on the Maximum Bytes scanned by a normal query (per user/per project) but it seems that the same setting does not apply to Scheduled Queries.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Future References,

There is no direct way of getting scheduled query limit bytes.
The only thing scheduled query displays is the duration it takes to set up and actual implementation, which is kind of flakky.

The onbly way to get Scheduled Query Limit Bytes is to go to

**SQL Workspace -> Query History -> Project History**
[image]

There you should see the details of the query with scanned bytes and time of processing.